# Cleaning up filenames within a directory

Tags: bash, sed, awk, rename

I would like to run a bash script that recursively cleans up every filename in a directory. For example I have the filename:

The.Sarah.Jane.Adventures.S04E07.The.Empty.Planet.Part1.WS.PDTV.XviD-BiA.[sharethefiles.com].avi
The.Sarah.Jane.Adventures.S04E08.The.Empty.Planet.Part2.WS.PDTV.XviD-BiA.[sharethefiles.com].avi

I want to convert the file to:

The Sarah Jane Adventures S04E07 The Empty Planet Part1.avi

The Sarah Jane Adventures S04E07 The Empty Planet Part2.avi

So I have this sed script:

```
sed -e's/\[sharethefiles\.com\]//g; s/WS//g; s/PDTV//g; s/Xvid-BiA//g; s/XviD-BiA//g; s/\.\.//g; s/\./\ /g;'
```

but it comes with problems. The . (period) is removed before the suffix (avi) and I am not really sure how to replace it with files being so dynamic. Sometimes there maybe only one space before the suffix and sometimes there are none since the script also removes double periods.

Any ideas as to fixing the issue?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to convert *all* periods to spaces and then pipe into a command that sets the extension.

Example (ignoring the other special cases you indicated):

```
tr '.' ' ' | sed 's/ \([^ ]*\)$/.\1/'
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work fine enough for the purposes I want. With the special cases I ended up removing the space before the case happened and it worked just fine. Easy fix, blah... Thanks again!

Comment: @Ratty: You can eliminate the `tr` by replacing your next-to-last pattern with `s/\.\+/ /g` and replacing your last one with Gingi's pattern.